# Count number of rollbacks in SQL Sever 2008

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am experimenting with the `SET-OPTION XACT_ABORT ON` as I am seeing a lot of sleeping sessions holding an open transaction causing problems in the application.

Is there a way to measure if flipping the option has an effect or not? *I am thinking about something like number of rollbacks per day*. How could I collect these?

I am on **SQL Server 2008 SP4**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your database is in Full  Recovery Model.You can combine all the transaction log backups taken per day and Query it...

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN OPERATION='LOP_ABORT_XACT' THEN 'COMMITS'
ELSE 'ROLLBACKS' END AS 'OPERATIONS'
,COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM FN_DBLOG(NULL,NULL) WHERE OPERATION IN ('LOP_COMMIT_XACT','LOP_ABORT_XACT')
GROUP BY OPERATION
```

I did some tests using some sample data..

```
Begin tran test1
insert into t1
select 3
rollback
```

**Output:**

```
Operations  cnt
Commits     3
RollBacks   4
```

**Update as per comments:**
Reading Transaction log Backup can be expensive ,I recommend you do this on backups taken and not on Active log ..doing this on active Tlog can have below effects

1.since this does a Log Scan,[Transaction log truncation will be prevented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2.Huge IO load on server depending on Your log backup Size,[since  the output of ::fn_dblog can easily go into millions of rows](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/)

**References:**

http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dfurman/2009/11/05/reading-database-transaction-log-with-fn_dump_dblog/

Comment: This is not a bad ideea per-se, but consider that reading back the log, on an even moderate load server, would be *quite* expensive.

Comment: That's true,I would add more to clarify this

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. I'll just have to do a little work to perform it on a restored version.